# Select a layout for dynamically generated nuxt page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm building a project where all my data - including page routes - comes from a GraphQL endpoint but needs to be hosted via a static site (I know, I know. Don't get me started).

I've managed to generate routes statically from the data using the following code in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
 generate: {
    routes: () => {
      const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
      const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ uri })
      const query = `
          query Pages {
           pages {
            slug
            template
            pageContent {
             replaced
             components {
              componentName
              classes
             body
            }
          }
        }
      }
      `

      return apolloFetch({ query }) // all apolloFetch arguments are optional
        .then(result => {
          const { data } = result
          return data.pages.map(page => page.slug)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('got error')
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  }
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that some pages need to use a different layout from the default, the correct layout to use is specified in the GraphQL data as `page.template` but I don't see any way to pass that information to the router.

I've tried changing `return data.pages.map(page => page.slug)` to:

```
  return data.pages.map(page => {
     route: page.slug,
     layout: page.template
    })
```

but that seems to be a non-starter. Does anyone know how to pass a layout preference to the vue router?

Comment: in the docs it says: "dynamic routes are ignored by the generate command: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes" - but it's just a wild guess

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to inject the data into a payload
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-code-payload-code-
This will allow you to pass generate information into the route itself.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing :)

Then I said 'screw it' when the next issue arose and just switched to Gatsby. :)

Comment: Have you considered Gridsome?

Comment: Link above is broken, so here it is [the new link to the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-payload)